# how to split application server

Tags: .net

The application is video-streaming site. Its all in one server like application, uploaded videos and database. Now what i need is to split into two servers from one, then application, db on one server and uploaded files on another server. Is there anything i need to configure in IIS or need to code in .net? How to map the application from 1st server to upload video files to another server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to add video files on the database server?

Comment: just i need application and database in one server. Only end user uploading videos should directly to another server.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution is to create a shared folder on the video storing server and map this share to disk letter on application server.